# Running SSL multiple VHOSTS with one IP

Tags: ssl, apache-2.2, rewrite

I have a site running Apache and it contains multiple VHOSTS. I don't have an option to setup the machine with multiple IP addresses, but I would like to have some way of accessing each VHOST somehow over SSL. Is there a way to do this?

I guess I can't expect https://realhttps, https://vhost1 and https://vhost2 to work, but is there an easy way to configure mod_rewrite to make https://realhttps/vhost1 fetch content from http://vhost1 and https://realhttps/vhost2 fetch content from http://vhost2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nearly a FAQ, but I couldn't (rapidly) find another answer, so:

You want Server Name Indication, aka SNI.  The theory is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication , the practical for Apache is at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI .

The problem is that it requires a fairly modern apache, and a fairly modern SSL, and (this is the killer) browser support.  Read those two pages and you should know if SNI is suitable for you.

If it's not, restate the mod_rewrite question.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't what I was looking for, but it's better than what I was looking for an the requirement for new browser is ok. Thank you.